# Access another controller in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My basic code so far:

```
function UsersCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "usersName": "Matt Dance",
            "favorites": {
                "id":1,
                "lodge_id":1
            }
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "usersName": "Jennifer Dance",
            "favorites": {
                "id":1,
                "lodge_id":2
            }
        }
    ];
};

function LodgesCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.lodges = [
        {
            id: 1,
            lodgesName: 'Matt\'s Awesome Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Matthew D',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '5555 J lane',
            lodgeCity: 'Salt Lake city',
            lodgeZip: '11111',
            lodgeState: 'Utah'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            lodgesName: 'Some Historic Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Santa Claus',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 Clearwater Road',
            lodgeCity: 'Grand Marais',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Minnesota'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            lodgesName: 'Yellowstone Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'The Feds',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 Yellowstone Way',
            lodgeCity: 'Yellowstone',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Wyoming'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            lodgesName: 'Cool Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Awesome Guy',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 awesome Road',
            lodgeCity: 'Eagle Mountain',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Utah'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            lodgesName: 'The last lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Adam V',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '444 Last Road',
            lodgeCity: 'San Francisco',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'California'
        }
    ];
};
```

I want the user to be able to see the lodge name of the lodge they favorited. For example, a user favorites a lodge with the id of 1. How then can I loop through each user, and display the title of the lodge which the favorited? Basically, I need to use the `lodge_id` for each user in their favorites to display the lodge name.

My html is thus far:

```
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.usersName}}<br>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm new to Angular (and JS frameworks in general), and am not sure how to go about this. I've looked into other frameworks like Ember, but havn't been able to solve it in an "easy" way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to construct a mapping object and bind it to $rootScope. For example:

```
$rootScope.mapping = {
    userId: [lodge1, lodge2...]
}
```

Comment: This essentially maps a user id with several lodge id's... correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've made few changes on your code and it is working now BUT I think you need to structure your data in a better way so you can do your iteration in a much easier way.

You can also see a working plunker here (http://plnkr.co/edit/DtBxzYulJGTQC0KJsh8M?p=preview).

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "usersName": "Matt Dance",
            "favorites": {
                "id":1,
                "lodge_id":1
            }
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "usersName": "Jennifer Dance",
            "favorites": {
                "id":1,
                "lodge_id":2
            }
        }
    ];

    $scope.lodges = [
        {
            id: 1,
            lodgesName: 'Matt\'s Awesome Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Matthew D',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '5555 J lane',
            lodgeCity: 'Salt Lake city',
            lodgeZip: '11111',
            lodgeState: 'Utah'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            lodgesName: 'Some Historic Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Santa Claus',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 Clearwater Road',
            lodgeCity: 'Grand Marais',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Minnesota'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            lodgesName: 'Yellowstone Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'The Feds',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 Yellowstone Way',
            lodgeCity: 'Yellowstone',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Wyoming'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            lodgesName: 'Cool Lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Awesome Guy',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '1 awesome Road',
            lodgeCity: 'Eagle Mountain',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'Utah'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            lodgesName: 'The last lodge',
            lodgeOwnersName: 'Adam V',
            lodgeStreetAddress: '444 Last Road',
            lodgeCity: 'San Francisco',
            lodgeZip: '55555',
            lodgeState: 'California'
        }
    ];
   }]);


   </script>

    </head>
    <body>

 <div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.usersName}}<br>
    {{user.favorites.lodge_id}}<br>
        <p ng-repeat="lodge in lodges | filter: { id: user.favorites.lodge_id }">
            {{lodge.lodgesName}}
        </p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I believe mdance is asking how does two controllers talk to each other. Your solution only has one controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service. Since services are singletons, they are the easiest way to share content among controllers. In fact, it's the angular way:

> **Do not use controllers for:**
>
> Sharing stateless or stateful code across controllers — Use angular
> services instead.

[Developer Guide/Understanding the Controller Component](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller)

Comment: Please note that the text you have quoted talks about sharing "code" and not about sharing data. In fact the AngularJS FAQ states this: "Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data". The FAQ actually tells that $rootScope might and probably should be used for this. I'm not sure if I totally agree with their recommendations, though, and others have also expressed doubts about this.

Comment: So, what is considered best practice? Ultimately I'm sharing data, not code. It has been unclear so far as to the best way to go about this.